# Google Sheets Alphabetic order ranking

Tags: google-sheets

How can I get the alphabetical (lexicographical) order or rank of a string with respect to other strings?

Note: I do NOT want to sort an array.

Example:

```
=Rank(1, {1,7,5}) // yields 3
```

but

```
=Rank("Apple", {"Orange", "Banana", "Apple"}) // yields error
```

I want an equivalent function that yields `1` since `Apple` is the first lexicographically.

I found a function but I wonder if there is a better more efficient alternative:

```
=match("a",sort(transpose({"b","a", "c"})))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the last formula in your post by getting rid of `TRANSPOSE` and changing the delineator between list words from a comma to a semicolon:

`=match("a",sort({"b"; "a"; "c"}))`

That is about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
=MATCH("Apple", {"Orange", "Banana", "Apple"},0)
```